# Index out of range in fetchAll()

Tags: android, android-sqlite

In Android I'm using the following statement:

```
return bdd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_EVENTS , new String[]{"titre","emplacement"});
```

and it throws the error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0x3e1360
```

Comment: Check spelling maybe, I see "titre", is it suppose to be "title"?

Comment: yes, you are giving selection args without placeholders for them. what exactly are you expecting "titre", "emplacement" to be used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the `selectionArgs` parameter without using the same number of `?`s in the WHERE clause of your query. I'm guessing that you want:

```
return bdd.rawQuery("SELECT titre, emplacement FROM " + TABLE_EVENTS, null);
```